# Understanding the working of $watch

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to understand how $watch works by an example, but its not working. In the example, I am watching a array called favorites which is within the $scope. If the favorites array changes, I expect to write the new value in the console. Not sure if this is the right way to use the $watch.

Controller code

```
var mods = angular.module("listApp",[])
    mods.controller("prodCtlr", function($scope){
            $scope.favorites = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]     

            $scope.delete = function(index){
                $scope.favorites.splice(index,1)
            }

            $scope.$watch(function(){
                return $scope.favorites;
            }, function(newVal, oldVal){

                console.log(newVal);

            })

        }
    );
```

HTML

```
        <table class="table table-striped">
           <tr ng-repeat="fav in favorites">
            <td>{{fav}}</td><td><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete!" ng-click="delete($index)" ng-model="fav"></input></td>
            </tr>
       </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [$watchCollection](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection):

```
$scope.favorites = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
$scope.dataCount = 4;

$scope.$watchCollection('favorites', function(newFavs, oldFavs) {
  $scope.dataCount = newFavs.length;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use with deep watch, like this:

```
$scope.$watch('favorites', function(newFavs, oldFavs) {
  $scope.dataCount = newFavs.length;
}, true);
```

$watch() will be triggered by:

```
$scope.myArray = [];
$scope.myArray = null;
$scope.myArray = someOtherArray;
```

$watchCollection() will be triggered by everything above AND:

```
$scope.myArray.push({}); // add element
$scope.myArray.splice(0, 1); // remove element
$scope.myArray[0] = {}; // assign index to different value
```

$watch(..., true) will be triggered by EVERYTHING above AND:

```
$scope.myArray[0].someProperty = "someValue";
```

Additional Note: $watch(..., true) will not be triggered when the monitored object is rebuilt. While $watchCollection(...,true) will be triggered on rebuild.